# How important is whitespace inside parens in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I just discovered that whitespace inside parens can matter in Ruby in an unexpected way:
Here are 3 functions which look semantically identical to me:

```rb
def foo(x)
     return {
      :a => (x - 100),
    }
end

def bar(x)
     return {
       :a => (x
              - 100),
    }
end

def zot(x)
     return {
       :a => (x -
              100),
    }
end
```

However, `foo(10)` and `zot(10)` return `{:a=>-90}` (as I expected) while `bar(10)` returns `{:a=>-100}` (to my dismay and disappointment).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an unusual case here but I believe what you're seeing is Ruby interpreting that as several *consecutive statements* and not a single statement. As in it sees that as:

```
x    # Statement 1
-100 # Statement 2
```

Where the result of that block of code is `-100`.

In the case of `zot` you've expressed your intent to continue that line on the next by having a dangling `-` binary operator:

```
x - # Statement 1
100 # Statement 1 (cont)
```

It's worth noting that you can't do this when making method calls:

```
zot(x
 -100  # Syntax error
)
```

As in that case the argument syntax rules are a lot more strict. Inside a free-form `(...)` structure you have considerably more latitude.

Comment: Yup, `(x\n - 100)` will be parsed as two expressions, hence returning the last.

Comment: @DaveNewton Since `-` is simply a method call the `Object` represented by `x`, we can correct this by explicitly making a method call via `(x\n .-(100) )` Same applies to tadman's final note.

Comment: @engineersmnky *Could* ;)

Comment: @engineersmnky Pretty sure [Rubocop](https://www.github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop) will bash down your door and tell you to step away from the keyboard if you do that.

Comment: @tadman pretty sure if I wanted to be told how to use whitespace I'd use python 

Answer (score 4):

In Ruby, there are two possible expression separators: semicolon `;` and newline.

So,

```
a
b
```

is the same as

```
a; b
```

Which means that

```
a
- b
```

is the same as

```
a; - b
```

which is the same as

```
a; b.-@()
```

Of course, you expected it to be equivalent to

```
a - b
```

which is the same as

```
a.-(b)
```

The point is: each of those two interpretations is equally valid. The language designer has to choose one of those two interpretations, and in this case, they chose the first one. Neither of the two is more "right" or more "correct".

If they had chosen the second interpretation, then you wouldn't have asked this question, but someone else would have asked the opposite one.